# Can't Simplify this equation for a Ellipse(Complex Numbers)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers, conic-sections

I'm asked to sketch the set $\{z \in C : |z + i| + |z + 1| = 2\}$.

I've gotten to the point where I've got the modulus form of $|z + i| + |z + 1|$:
$$\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2} + \sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} = 2$$
How do I change this to the equation for an ellipse?

Comment: This is the equation of a ellipse. You are not changing anything. It is an ellipse whose sum of distances from the 2 focal points is 2. The focal points are $-i$ and $-1$ which are $(0,-1)$ and $(-1,0)$. However, if you insist on changing to X-Y, then there are very interesting ways on how to eliminate the XY terms and get conics (2-D, 3-D) in a standard form using some linear alegbra - eigen values etc or simply by completing the squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's expand your formula.
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}=2\\
&\iff\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}=2-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}\\
&\iff x^2+y^2+2y+1=4-4\sqrt{x^2+2x+1+y^2}+x^2+2x+1+y^2\\
&\iff \sqrt{x^2+2x+1+y^2}=1-\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{2}x\\
&\iff \frac{3}{4}x^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2+\frac{1}{2}xy+x+y=0\\
&\iff 3x^2+2xy+3y^2+4x+4y=0  
\end{align*}

Note that the last equation represents a conic section. Its discriminant is clearly smaller than 0, so it represents a circle or ellipse. However, it can't be a circle, since we have nonzero $xy$ term.

Actually, we can perform the following change of variables,
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
x&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u-v)\\
y&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u+v)\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation*}

Then, we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(u+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{\frac{1}{2}}+v^2=1
\end{equation*}
This is clearly an ellipse

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why?

Comment: Thank you I understand it now!

Comment: @Y.Fan Perhaps because you gave a full answer rather than a hint; which to be honest is all OPs are looking for. Then again; I see your answer has 3 up-votes so what do I know :-)